# Logstash, how can I add field depending on output?

Tags: input, filter, output, logstash

I have one jdbc input which I need to send to two different outputs (http and influxdb).
I need to add fields depending on the output.
I was hoping I could use add_field during the output stage but it is only available during input and filter stages.
Can someone suggest a solution?
Logstash 2.4

Eg.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "select col1, col2..."  
    ...
    }
}
filter {

}
output {

    http {
    #need to add/remove field here for http output
    }

    influxdb {
    #need to add/remove field here for influxdb output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Near the end of your filter chain, add a `clone` filter with type `clones` values.  The `clone` filter duplicates the event and sets `type` on the clone.  After that add an `if`/`else` block that adds the fields you want.  Finally surround your outputs with `if` blocks.

Something like this:

```
filter {
  clone { clones => [ "http", "influx"] }
  if ([type] == "http") {
     mutate {}
  } else if ([type] = "influx") {
     mutate {}
  } else {
     drop {}
  }
}
output {
  if ([type] == "http") {
    http {}
  }
  if ([type] == "influx") {
    influxdb {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the clone filter is what will help. I also used some @metadata field and dropped type field to avoid having it show up in the output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiple outputs will send the same event to those outputs.  You can add a field in the input{} or filter{} sections, but it would be sent to both.

If the outputs are conditional, you can have that same conditional in your filter section to add the unique fields.